# Sublime Text There are no packages available for installation without proxy settings

Tags: proxy, installation, sublimetext3, package-control

i'm using sublime text 3. At work we have proxy connection so i edited sublime settings and voila i can install packages through proxy.

But when i get home and try to install new package after removed proxy lines from sublime settings it says "There are no packages available for installation"

I disabled all kind of proxy settings on my computer but it's seems like it's still trying install through proxy.

Here is the error i get;

```
Package Control: Error downloading channel. URL error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known downloading https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json.
```

I'm using MacOSX El Capitan

Comment: I am too in the same boat. I don't think it is a proxy issue since I was able to Install `Package Control`. Even checking updates do not fail. Thus, I am assuming internet connectivity should be fine.

Comment: Update: I was able to install packages after restarting Sublime. Not sure the reason. Then it was looking for a `Default` directory for settings. This worked for me `ln -sv User Default` in this directory `/Users/vikas/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`